# onChanged property of TextField vanishes on clicking done button after entering text in keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-ui, textfield, state-management, flutter-android

```
class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddTaskScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String newTask = '';
    return Container(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Add Task',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.amber[900],
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  newTask = value;
                },
                autofocus: true,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 111, 0, 1)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<TaskData>(context, listen: false).addTask(newTask);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amber[900],
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'Add',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The data gets added to screen if I directly click the add button without clicking the done button on keyboard.
But on clicking done button after entering the text,
I get this line on the debug console.

```
I/TextInputPlugin( 6522): Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.
```

Although after clicking add button after clicking done on the keyboard, an empty field is added.

I have tried using a controller and that just saves the text onto the keyboard statically, but does not help in adding the text to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on done button in soft keyboard triggers the **onSubmitted** method, not onChanged method, make sure to override it as well

Comment: Hi Sanketh. A small mistake made by me. Had to declare this code before build().
String newTask = '';
Thank you for the inputs.